# Ошибка: requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='elibrary.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /title_about.asp?id=8720

Tags: python-3.x

Пытаюсь получить код страницы:

```
        response = requests.get('https://elibrary.ru/title_about.asp?id=8720', verify=certifi.where())
        try:
            doc = response.content.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')
        except:
            doc = response.content.decode('cp1251', errors='ignore')
```

Но программа выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 849, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 356, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 359, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 850, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='elibrary.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /title_about.asp?id=8720 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ISagitova/Desktop/Py/parsJurnArticle.py", line 17414, in <module>
    g = get_write()
  File "C:/Users/ISagitova/Desktop/Py/parsJurnArticle.py", line 497, in get_write
    response = requests.get('https://elibrary.ru/title_about.asp?id=8720', verify=certifi.where())
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 512, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 622, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ISagitova\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 511, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='elibrary.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /title_about.asp?id=8720 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)')))
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему. Заранее благодарна за ответ

Comment: Вам надо переставить openssl на более новый и собрать python3 с новым openssl. Это не проблема в python. Ваш код рабочий.

Comment: @Axenow, спасибо Вам за комментарий. Установила вот так: pip install pyopenssl. Но ошибку всё равно выдаёт. Надо как-то по-другому было сделать?

Comment: Вам надо не pyopenssl поставить, а в системе openssl переустановить.